# Using malloc to create a chunk of memory equivalent to struct

Tags: c++

I want to create a chunk of memory equivalent to a struct using malloc as shown in the code below, but I get the warning "C6378 'pMyStructByMalloc' could be '0'" and can't seem to get it to work.

```
    struct MyStruct
    {
        int a = 1;
        std::string s = "test";
        int b = 2;
    };
    MyStruct* pMyStruct = new MyStruct();

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    std::string s = "test";

    int memorySize = sizeof(int) + sizeof(std::string) + sizeof(int);
    char* pMyStructByMalloc = (char*)malloc(memorySize);
    memcpy(pMyStructByMalloc, &a, sizeof(int)); // C6378 'pMyStructByMalloc' could be '0'
    memcpy((pMyStructByMalloc + sizeof(int)), &s, sizeof(std::string));
    memcpy((pMyStructByMalloc + sizeof(int) + +sizeof(std::string)), &b, sizeof(int));
```

Is there any way to do this successfully?

Using malloc to create a chunk of memory equivalent to struct.

---

Postscript.
ok, so what if the structure has a fixed length and is

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int a = 1;
  float s = 10.0f;
  int b = 2;
};
```

I am trying to see if I can "fake" the same kind of memory and send a chunk of memory to a certain low-level function without using any MyStruct.(Assuming I have no reference to the MyStruct code, but only know the data structure)

---

Potscript 2

API is looks like following

```
TheAPI(int32 bufferSize, void * data);
```

I usually do this,

```
TheAPI(sizeof(MyStruct), pMyStruct);
```

but this time I want to do this dynamically

```
TheAPI(memorySize , pMyStructByMalloc)
```

this way, I can experiment with different forms of memory.(different type of fixed size struct)

Comment: malloc, memcpy... not thing usually found in modern C++ anymore (the whole idea of C++ is to use abstractions, and usually those abstractions are already as close to zero overhead as needed). Not to mention with this technique you will not end up with a valid struct anyway. You have a std::string member and its lifetime (constructor) will never get called. So what is it you really want to achieve?  because this approach is just an accident waiting to happen (Undefined Behavior)

Comment: `int memorySize = sizeof(int) + sizeof(std::string) + sizeof(int);` is wrong.  The rioght way to do it is `int memorySize = sizeof(MyStruct);`

Comment: also `memcpy` and `std::string` **do not mix**

Comment: This code calculates the member offsets incorrectly, as it does not take into account padding.  (Theoretically, the buffer could also be misaligned.).  `memcpy` of a `std::string` to copy it is broken.  That's not how to copy a non-POD object.

Comment: If you want to have a chunk of memory that is equivalent then give MyStruct a copy constructor and use that

Comment: `malloc` can return the null pointer. The warning is there because you didn't check. (But that is the least of your problem.)

Comment: `std::string s = "test";` -- This is fools gold.  This *may* work due to short-string-optimization, and thus seems it will work all the time.  But as soon as the text is much larger, the whole `memcpy` thing will fall apart since the `std::string` class will be using dynamically allocated memory and a pointer to the buffer.

Comment: Submit your code to codereview.stackexchange.com, there's a bunch to improve. Do read their site guidelines first, though! For questions here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. You are also expected to extract and provide a [mcve].

Comment: [MyStruct is not trivially-copyable](https://godbolt.org/z/75zPe5957).  Note that `MyStruct2` at the linked code *is* trivially-copyable.  Do you see the difference in the two structs?

Comment: Never use `malloc()` in C++. Your future self will thank you. Users of your code will thank you. Readers of your code will thank you. Your code will be a better place. The world will be a better place. Look at placement `new` and placement `delete` and the plethora of templates and macros and builtins that deal with sizing and alignment.

Comment: "I am trying to see if I can "fake" MyStruct " what does that mean exactly? Why do you need to "fake" it? Why can you not simply pass a `MyStruct a;` to that low level function?

Comment: you need to have the definition available to "fake" it properly, so you can as well us `MyStruct` itself rather than your fake. This is clearly a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). We can help you better if you explain why you need that fake for. What is that low level function? Why not use an actual `MyStruct` ?

Comment: The API I'm trying to deal with now can be executed as long as it has a byte length and a chunk of memory. In other words, I want to construct a chunk of bytes of arbitrary length without defining a struct.

Comment: " I want to construct a chunk of bytes of arbitrary length without defining a struct." `std::vector<byte>` ? What does this have to do with `MyStruct` ?

Comment: API is looks like following
TheAPI(int32 bufferSize, void * data);

I usually do this, 
TheAPI(sizeof(MyStruct), pMyStruct);

but this time I want to do this dynamically
TheAPI(memorySize , pMyStructByMalloc)
this way, I can experiment with different forms of memory.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try std::vector<byte> first.

Comment: Then you still have to get rid of std::string, too. But what kind of API is it? To send binary data over a network or something? If you want to do that you will need to serialize your data, not just copy it and then you need a serialization library (flatbuffer/protobuffer)

Comment: suppose you have a `MyStruct a;` then maybe all you need is `TheAPI(sizeof(MyStruct),static_cast<void*>(&a))`. Or maybe not. It depends on what `TheAPI` is.

Answer (score 2):

To copy a struct, provide a copy constructor.
This will ensure your std::string is also copied correctly and will have its lifetime started.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct() = default;
    ~MyStruct() = default;

    MyStruct(const MyStruct& rhs) :
        a{rhs.a},
        s{rhs.s},
        b{rhs.b}
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor";
    }

    // todo copy assignment, move constructor & move assignment
    
    int a = 1;
    std::string s = "test";
    int b = 2;
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct my_struct;
    auto copy_of_my_struct{my_struct};

    assert(copy_of_my_struct.a == 1);
    assert(copy_of_my_struct.s == std::string{"test"});
    assert(copy_of_my_struct.b == 2);
}
```

Comment: no need to manually provide a copy constructor or any of the other special member functions. The default will do the right thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver You are correct, this was to explicitly show what copying can do and when it will be called ;)

Comment: At least pretend to follow rule 3 and provide a `default`ed assignment operator please.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a buffer and you want it to represent an object you should use the [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) operator or c++20 [construct_at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) to invoke the constructor/copy constructor at a specific location, this guarantees the lifetime of objects is started (and prevent things like deleting unconstructed strings), you also need to call the destructor (or c++20 [destroy_at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at)) when you are no-longer using the object to free any resources.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MyStruct
{
    int a = 1;
    std::string s = "test";
    int b = 2;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> buffer = std::vector<char>(sizeof(MyStruct));
    MyStruct object1 = MyStruct();
    MyStruct* object2 = new (&buffer[0]) MyStruct{object1};
    object2->~MyStruct(); // destroy object to end its lifetime
    return 0;
}
```

note that `std::vector` has an alignment requirement to be aligned to any standard type, so it can be used to contain `MyStruct`, but if you are getting this memory from somewhere else (like malloc) you need to make sure the memory is correctly aligned, orelse the `placement new` operator will push the pointer forward to compensate for the alignment requirement.